# ¿Como corregir error de concatenar str en python3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, concatenación

Estoy corriendo el siguiente fraagmento de codigo de un paquete de ROS llamado [canusb](https://github.com/spiralray/canusb)

el cual se puede ver a continuacion:

```
def readline(self):
    """
    Overrides io.RawIOBase.readline which cannot handle with '\r' delimiters
    """
    ret = ''
    while True:
        c = self.read(1)
        if c == '':
            return ret
        elif c == '\r':
            if ret == 'z' or ret == 'Z':
                self.status = 0
            return ret + c
        elif c == chr(7):
            self.status = -1
            return c
        else:
            ret += c
```

Me esta saltando el siguiente error de la ultima linea:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/canusb.py", line 191, in <module>
    can.init()
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/canusb.py", line 57, in init
    line = self.readline()
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/canusb.py", line 51, in readline
    ret += c
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

¿Como se puede solucionar?

Un saludo y muchas gracias con antelación.
Alessandro

Comment: Usa `c=self.read(1).decode("utf-8")` para convertir bytes a string.

Comment: Perfecto, eso me solucionó el problema (no he usado mucho python por ello la obviedad de la pregunta). Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he solucionado convirtiendo bytes a string de la siguiente forma:

```
c=self.read(1).decode("utf-8")
```

Un saludo.